# Append different variable if JSON data contains undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, each

I'm working on parsing out an excel file to JSON, which overall works fine. But the catch it that I'm trying to figure out how to append different HTML if a variable contains specific text from the JSON.

So far this is what I have:

```
/* This is part of the Excel conversion. Added for reference */
var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

  var jData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: false });

  $.each(jData, function (i, f) {
    var hide = f.Hidden;
    var el =
     "<div class='thing'>" +
      "<h2>" +
      f["First Name"] +
      "&nbsp;" +
      f["Last Name"] +
      "</h2>" +
      "<h3>" +
      f.Title +
      "</h3>" +
      "<p>" +
      f.Comment +
      "</p>" +
      "</div>";
    $(el).appendTo("#wrapper");
  });
```

But what I'm curious about is making sure that this is valid:

```
$.each(jData, function (i, f) {
    var hide = f.Hidden;
    var el =
     "<div class='thing'>" +
      "<h2>" +
      f["First Name"] +
      "&nbsp;" +
      f["Last Name"] +
      "</h2>" +
      "<h3>" +
      f.Title +
      "</h3>" +
      "<p>" +
      f.Comment +
      "</p>" +
      "</div>";
    var other =
     "<div class='thing'>" +
      "<h2>" +
      f["First Name"] +
      "&nbsp;" +
      f["Last Name"] +
      "</h2>" +
      "<h3>" +
      f.Title +
      "</h3><p>Comment Hidden</p></div>";
    if (hide === undefined) {
       $(el).appendTo("#wrapper");
    } else {
      $(other).appendTo("#wrapper");
    }
  });
```

Overall, it *appears* to be working where if the `hide` variable comes back as `undefined` from the JSON data, then append the HTML elements from the `el` variable. But if it does come back as **not** undefined, then append the HTML from the `other` variable. I just want to be sure that I'm not missing anything. Also, if there might be a better way to go about this. It feels kinda "clunky" to me, but oddly enough it appears to work on the surface.

Comment: To be clear, if `f.Hidden` is `undefined` append to `el`, if `f.Hidden` is `true` ***OR*** `false` append `other` - is that right?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Umm, more like if `f.Hidden` does not return `undefined` then append `el`. Otherwise if it does  come back with something *not* `undefined` then return other. Basically when I `console.log` out the stuff form the JSON, the data from `f.Hidden` will either have something or not. If not then it comes back as `undefined` from the JSON. I know...this was messing with my head as well which is why I'm asking, lol!

Answer (score 1):

> If `f.Hidden` does not return `undefined` then append el

In this case you can use `typeof` to determine the state of the `f.Hidden` value. Also note that I avoided the repetition within the code by removing the comment text from the `p` when the `Hidden` property is defined.

```js
$.each(jData, function(i, f) {
  var $el = $(`<div class="thing"><h2>${f["First Name"]}&nbsp;${f["Last Name"]}</h2><h3>${f.Title}</h3><p>${f.Comment}</p></div>`);
  if (typeof f.Hidden !== 'undefined')         
    $el.find('p').text('Comment hidden');

  $('#wrapper').append($el);
});
```

One thing to note here is that this will show the comment if `f.Hidden` is `true` ***OR*** `false` - which seems counterintuitive.

If you want to hide the comment when `f.Hidden` is `undefined` or `true` (which would seem to make more sense), the code would look like this instead:

```js
$.each(jData, function(i, f) {
  var $el = $(`<div class="thing"><h2>${f["First Name"]}&nbsp;${f["Last Name"]}</h2><h3>${f.Title}</h3><p>${f.Comment}</p></div>`);
  if (f.Hidden || true)
    $el.find('p').text('Comment hidden');

  $('#wrapper').append($el);
});
```

The `|| true` will coerce any falsy value (such as `undefined`) to `true`.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Yeah, that was my concern overall was to make sure that the validation for the `undefined` was correct (not being true OR false as you noted). But this helps and clears it up. Thanks!